# TortioisHg with hgsubversion does not handle default remote repository in sync

Tags: hgsubversion, tortoisehg-2.0

I am using TortoiseHg 2.7.2 with most recent version of hgsubversion.

All works fine except for one issue related to the Sync dialog.

The URL for the remote repository (from which I originally cloned my local hg repo) is like this:

"svn+https://svn.newco.local:8443/svn/NEWCO"

However, when I open the Sync dialog the local hgrc file prefers /svn/NEWCO as the remote repository which is the svn folder in the remote svn repo.

I have saved the desired URL as 'default' in the Sync dialog but it is never picked up by the dialog automatically (it always defaults to /svn/NEWCO).

Obviously the svn+https seems to make TortoiseHg choke. Is there some way I can get the Sync dialog to populate the Remote Repository text box correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsequently I cloned the repository again and Hg behaves as expected. I cannot reproduce this problem now.